# subtract 2 numbers using char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, char

I wanted to subtract two char arrays which have numeric values. I am doing it because I want to subtract big numbers. When I compile this program,it does not show any errors but in the execution it crashes.
I tried to do as following pseudo code

```
foreach character(right2left)
    difference=n1[i]-n2[i]//here suppose they are integers
    if(difference<0)
    {
        n1[i-1]--;
        difference+=10;
    }
    result[i]=diff;
```

I wrote pseudo code for clarity.

```
 int subtract(char *n1,char *n2,int n1Len,int n2Len){
 int diff;  
    int max=n1Len;
  char* res = (char*)malloc (max+2);
    memset(res, '0', max +1); 

    res[max] = '\0';
    int i=n1Len - 1, j = n2Len - 1, k = max;
    for (; i >= 0 && j >=0; --i, --j, --k) {
    if(i >= 0 && j>=0)
    {
            diff=(n1[i]-'0') - (n2[i]-'0') ;
        if(diff<0)
        {
        int temp=n1[i-1]-'0';
        temp=temp-1;
        n1[i-1]=temp+'0';
        diff+=10;
        }
        res[i]=diff+'0';
   }
  else 
         res[i]=n1[i];

    }
    return atoi(res);
 }


int main(void) {
    int t=subtract("55","38",2,2);
    printf("%d\n", t);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a bignum class?

Comment: What is meant by `not run`? It does not compile? It does not give results you want? or It runs but crashes? Please just don't dump code on us and make us find that out. It is your problem so tell us your problem clearly and explicitly.

Comment: How? if it is advanced I shouldn't use it.this code is for some one whom is so beginner in C.

Comment: @AIs I edited it because it now executes but the output is 0 not the true answer(17)

Comment: You cannot assign to n1[], it is a string literal. (you misuse n1 to store the borrow) n1 as called by main() points to "53"; and is not assignable.

Comment: Ok I will write it in more details sorry.

Comment: n1 is ascii and when I assign `temp+'0'` I mean i computed the ascii

Comment: Why don't you step through the code in a debugger and see what happens at every step? This way you'll learn a lot more than if someone just gives you the answer...

Comment: it is my first day @ C compiler I was in java! now I am so newbie but this code was emergency how can i debug it? for my IDE I downloaded pelles C

Comment: Forget my code does anyone know how to implement subtraction of characters which are array numbers?

Comment: You're still passing string literals, but in the case of borrow try to write to `n1`, since string literals are immutable, that crashes. Try `char fst[] = "55", snd[] = "38"; t = subtract(fst,snd,2,2);`.

Comment: it would be much faster to do big numbers in **words** rather than in **chars**. also, `n1[i]-n2[i]` is enough, no need to `-'0'` in each element since they'll eliminate each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few visible mistakes. Hopefully these will provide you with some pointers:

1. You are passing string literals to the function & trying to modify them in the function. That is not valid and will most likely cause segmentation fault. Instead of `int t=subtract("55","38",2,2);` Maybe you can try:
   `char a[] = "55";`
   `char b[] = "38";`
   `int t=subtract(a,b,strlen(a), strlen(b));`
2. `max` should be `n1Len+1` to accommodate terminating `NUL` character in `res` char array. You can set it to `0` rather than `'0'` when initializing. `res[max] = '\0';` invokes undefined behavior as you access out of bound element, get rid of it. So use `memset(res,0,max)` instead. Or use `calloc` instead of `malloc`+`memset` as suggested by @pmg.
3. Don't typecast return value of `malloc` or `calloc` when coding in C
4. `for (; i >= 0 || j >=0; --i, --j, --k)` should actually be `for (; i >= 0 && j >=0; --i, --j, --k)` as neither `i` nor `j` should be `0`. You need to work on the function logic wherein `i!=j`.
5. `diff=n1[i]-'0'+n2[i]-'0'` should be `diff=(n1[i]-'0') - (n2[i]-'0')` as you are subtracting and not adding the digits
6. `res[i]=diff` is incorrect as you are setting the integer result as character value. Change it to `res[i]=diff+'0'` to set the character value

Hopefully this will get you started.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!!!! about your number1 I have another function of add that I strictly call them and it is working.about number 5 no it shouldn't be because when I write n1[i]-'0' I mean integer value of the n1 and I have n2[i]-'0' which will be decrease from n1 then we have this `n1-'0'-(n2-'0')` which will be the thing that I wrote I will try your other parts Thank you so much

Comment: oh you are right! I inversely wrote it now it will crashes! nothing will be shown.appologize

Comment: I mean in execute it tells me in a window negin.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @nikparsa: Argh! still not working? You checked all the stuff above?

Comment: is there anyway for example not using any of the malloc or calloc? can I get a zero array and then assign it?hmm?

Comment: @nikparsa: See [this link](http://www.ideone.com/JrzmA) to see the code which can get you started

Answer (score 2):

```
    char* res = (char*)malloc (max);
    memset(res, '0', max-1);      // set the result to all zeros
    res[max] = '\0';
```

Let's say `max` is 3.
You set `res[0]`, and `res[1]` to 0. Then you set the inexistent `res[3]` to 0.
`res[2]` is still uninitialized.

Try `calloc` instead, and don't forget space for the zero string terminator :)

Also, casting the return value from `malloc` (or `calloc`) is, at best, redundant and may hide an error the compiler would have caught if the cast wasn't there.

```
    char *res = calloc(max + 1, 1); // allocate and initialize to 0
```

Comment: Thanks I dunno calloc would you please tell me?

Comment: I like the [POSIX site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) for quick reference to many function, including [calloc()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/calloc.html). Some of the functions (or their usage) described there are POSIX specific, but they are easily identifiable and you can avoid them if you want to write portable C.

Comment: Thanks but It still returns the zero.

Comment: ok i will change the return from int to char* and I will return res to see what will be

Comment: I couldn't get any result still.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
diff=n1[i]-'0'+n2[i]-'0';
```

should be the difference

```
diff = (n1[i] - '0') - (n2[j] - '0');
```

(besides subtracting and not adding, the index for `n2`  ought to be `j`, I think). With adding, you can get non-digit characters in the result, and `atoi()` stops at the first of them, if that's the very first, it returns 0.

Also, you should check that `n2` is indeed not longer than `n1`, or you'll write out of bounds.

Comment: yes you are right! I corrected now it will show me nothing it crashes on the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff=n1[i]-'0'+n2[i]-'0';
```

this does not give the difference.It should be

```
diff = (n1[i] - '0') - (n2[j] - '0');
```

Comment: In fact you're still passing char string, as `char[]` is an equivalent for `char*` in function parameter. `n1Len` and `n2Len` are optional if he's using normal string, because they're 0-terminated.